# Book series where a magic gauntlet fuses with a girl's arm and turns into a sword

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

The story starts off with a boy travelling on a ship which is carrying a chest.

The ship crashes and he and a girl get saved by a man who also took the chest.

The girl ends up opening the chest and a gauntlet inside fuses with her arm and turns into a sword.

As the three travel, the boy finds out he has a special "sight" ability which he uses to trick a con man playing a stone under three cups game, after he guesses right that there's no stone.

I can't remember the gist of the middle of the story, but I remember it ending with the boy being blinded and the girl getting him a puppy, which he lets her know he can see through with his gift again.

I read this about 14-18 years ago and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi. Do you recall roughly how many books there were in the series? Also, was it a new series at the time you read it, or older?

Comment: I believe there were 3 books in the series?
The last book was new at the time but I remember getting the series as a whole as a present from my Gran.

Comment: I can't seem to find it, but I could have sworn there was another recent question about a character who gained the ability to see through the shell game con.

Comment: I know the evil guy in the storyline has the same power as the boy, and part of the plot I believe is that he is after the sword and becomes interested in getting the boy too.

Comment: The part about the girl and the sword reminded me of WitchBlade, but the rest doesn't seem to fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Coming of Dragons](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/712725.The_Coming_of_Dragons) by A. J. Lake, first book in the [Darkest Age series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/92533-the-darkest-age). It was published in 2006 so that fits the time you remember reading it.

[image]

> Edmund, a king’s son in disguise, and Elspeth, a sea captain’s tomboy daughter, are the only two survivors of a terrible shipwreck. They just want to go home, but fate has other plans as they are drawn into the fight against an evil warlord terrorizing their homeland. Accompanied by a mysterious minstrel and haunted by magical powers they did not seek, Edmund and Elspeth journey across a savage land of wild boars, fierce rogue knights, and black magic.

As you describe, Elspeth opens the chest and:

> She turned back to the chest. Slowly, she slid the lock out of the wards and pulled them up. The lid swung open soundlessly, as though its hinges had just been oiled instead of soaked with sea. The chest exhaled a sour whiff of ancient air.
>
> Inside, it was dark unvarnished wood, giving back no reflection from the candlelight. At first Elspeth thought it was empty, but something glimmered at the bottom. She bent in for a closer look and the thing grew brighter, as if a pale flame suddenly shone within it.
>
> It was a gauntlet made of finely wrought silver facets, each one overlapping its neighbour so they rippled like the scales of some magical fish. Elspeth’s eyes widened. Surely no silver mined from the earth could have that living shimmer? Or perhaps some minuscule creatures from the sea’s depths, those that shine with their own light, had attached themselves to the surface of the gauntlet as the waves turned it over and over. And yet that couldn’t be, for the inside of the chest was bone dry.
>
> Entranced, she reached down to touch it. The cry that rang round the cave froze Edmund’s blood. He flung up his arms like a shield as a white light blinded him.
> But in a moment it was gone. When the light’s dazzle had cleared, Edmund saw Aagard staring open-mouthed across the cave.
>
> Elspeth stood before them, her right arm held straight out as if it were stone. On her hand was a shimmering, silver gauntlet – and in her grasp was a sword of pure, translucent crystal.

Comment: This is it! I can now rebuy a solid series, thanks a lot!